# How to solve an error of an Excel control code in a message receive procedure?

Tags: excel, delphi

I try to print something on an Excel worksheet when a message received.

I use Windows 10 and Delphi 10 Seattle.

This code works well.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Worksheet.Cells.Item[1, 1] := 1;
end;
```

But this doesn't and 'an outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call' happens.

```
procedure TForm1.onMessageReceived(var message: TMessage);
begin
  Worksheet.Cells.Item[1, 1] := 1;
end;
```

Same codes but different results according to procedures in which they are implemented.

How can I solve it?

Comment: It's difficult to know what onMessageReceive is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in control of the message sender, consider changing it from using SendMessage() to using PostMessage() instead.

Otherwise, in your message handler, store the information you receive and use an Application.OnIdle event to pass it to Excel.

Comment: thanks. i will try it tomorrow. today the server has stopped. it seems to be going to work.